# Laravel excel, reading horizontally

Tags: php, excel, laravel, laravel-5.4

Currently using Laravel-Excel (Maatwebsite) package for uploading excel and read them. Problem is, how to read horizontal and vertical data in a same excel file?

My excel file looks like this-

[image]

So far, this is my codes but it didnt read anything

```
$rows = Excel::load('storage\\app\\public\\upload\\Funiture.xlsx)->get();

@foreach ($rows as $key => $value)
    <tr>
      <td>{{ $value->{'Furniture Registration Number'} }}</td>
      <td>{{ $value->{'Number'} }}</td>
      <td>{{ $value->{'Chair Name'} }}</td>
      <td>{{ $value->{'Table Name'} }}</td>
      <td>{{ $value->{'Carpet Color'} }}</td>
   </tr>
@endforeach
```

**EDIT**

```
$rows = Excel::load('storage\\app\\public\\upload\\Funiture.xlsx)->get();
<span>Furniture Registration Number : <b>{{ $rows[0][1] }}</b></span>

$rows = Excel::load('storage\\app\\public\\upload\\Funiture.xlsx, function($reader){$reader->noHeading(); $reader->skipRows(3); })->get();;

@foreach ($rows as $key => $value)
  <tr>
    <td>{{ $value->[0] }}</td>
    <td>{{ $value->[1] }}</td>
    <td>{{ $value->[2] }}</td>
    <td>{{ $value->[3] }}</td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

Is it correct?

**EDIT**

[image]

This is result of dd(rows). How do I retrieve the amount of array? In this case, it have 7 as shown in the picture

Comment: Laravel-Excel use first row to set key for data. In your excel file there is no proper header. That's why its not working try adding proper header and then check

Comment: not quite understand about header, did you mean my header is "Number", "Chair Name", "Table Name" and "Carpet Name"?

Comment: It simply means that when it read data from file it set first row columns value to set keys for object/array that it return. For example in your case it will return collection of object each of which has key furniture_registration _umber,furniture_2xyz and 0

Comment: They way you read file twice will work but its not recommended to read same file twice you can use array_slice  to skip first 3 rows. Check my updated answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Laravel-Excel documentation says:

> By default the first row of the excel file will be used as attributes
>   .

So you need to define proper heading for first row if you want to use attribute. Otherwise you can do one thing just egnore heading

Try this

```
   $rows= Excel::load("storage\\app\\public\\upload\\Funiture.xlsx", function($reader) {
       $reader->noHeading();
        $reader->skipRows(3); // skip first three rows as they contain headings
    })->get();
    $rows = $rows->toArray();
```

And then in your view you can loop through the rows like this

```
@foreach ($rows as $key => $value)
    <tr>
      <td>{{ $value[0] }}</td>
      <td>{{ $value[1] }}</td>
      <td>{{ $value[2] }}</td>
      <td>{{ $value[3] }}</td>
   </tr>
    @endforeach
```

**EDIT :**

You don't need to read file twice just read file without skipping 3 rows and then use [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to skip first 3 rows after reading value at index `[0][1]`.

```
     $rows= Excel::load("storage\\app\\public\\upload\\Funiture.xlsx", function($reader) {
           $reader->noHeading();
     })->get();
   $rows = $rows->toArray();
```

Then in your view

```
<span>Furniture Registration Number : <b>{{ $rows[0][1] }}</b></span>
@php
    $rows = array_slice($rows,4);
@endphp

@foreach ($rows as $key => $value)
  <tr>
    <td>{{ $value->[0] }}</td>
    <td>{{ $value->[1] }}</td>
    <td>{{ $value->[2] }}</td>
    <td>{{ $value->[3] }}</td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: ah I see, I tested and works great, but it only read the vertical data only, how to read the horizontal one? The one with the "Furniture Registration Number"

Comment: What do you mean by horizontal one ?

Comment: I wanted to read the string at coordinate position of (B1) as shown in the picture at my question. Is it possible?

Comment: It reads "Chair-abc", maybe because the code skips 3 rows. Wanted to read the (B1) and the other value as well

Comment: Right it read "Chair-abc" because you skipp first 3 rows. 
Accept my answer If it works for you :)

Comment: is there any ways to read the (B1) and the other value as well?

Comment: It gives you a 2D array after reading values from file. Now you can use them just a simple array and access the value acoording to your need that's it. In case you want to read first row and then skip next 2 just do a simple for loop and skip row where index 1 and 2

Comment: i will post my code see if the my code is correctly written or not according to your reply

Comment: Tested, and this is the exact thing that i needed to do, thank you very much! There is another small thing that I need to ask. I will update my question.

Comment: nvm founded the solution